# How to search in gmail's trash via imap?

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

First a bit of code:

```py
import imaplib
from pprint import pprint

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: GenerateOAuth2String(self.email, self.password, base64_encode=False))
imap.select('"[Google Mail]/All Mail"')  # Doesn't work either: '[Google Mail]/Bin'

query = "in:trash"

pprint(imap.search(None, 'X-GM-RAW', f'"{query}"'))
```

I'm just wondering why this code doesn't work (ie: it doesn't return anything). It doesn't fail, it just returns no message nums.

When I do the same in gmail, it shows all entries.

Neither selecting the bin works...

What I'm looking for is how I could select a message in the trash through IMAP.

When I do `print(imap.search(None, 'ALL'))`, I do get a huge list of message_nums. So it seems to be working that way, but I hoped to reduce this list and not fetch all messages to do the querying myself.